# iOS 4.2.1 missing file?

Tags: iphone, file, ios

This is the first time I've used the newest xcode (3.2.5) and the new iOS (4.2.1) and I'm getting the following run time error as soon as I run my application on my device:

Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).

Does anyone have a cohesive answer to fix this? And yes I know there is another post on this topic, but it has not made any progress and there is not a clear cut answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I just did to solve this problem was:

```
cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols
```

and created the symlink was missing:

```
ln -s ../../4.2\ \(8C134\)/Symbols/Developer/ Developer
```

It solves my problem.

I'll post it in the other question also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you've done to try to solve it, but here's what I'd do, retrying between each step:

1. If you have that path but don't have the file, get it from someone (I'll volunteer). I'm guessing it's not that easy, though. :)
2. Delete and reinstall Xcode.
3. Go to the Xcode Organizer and plug in your device, and let it authorize and download the 4.2.1 stuff.
4. Do you even have a directory like that? I don't have those subdirectories (I don't have a `4.2.1 (8C148)` directory but I do have `4.2.1 (8C148a)`) there. Under DeviceSupport/Latest/ I have those subdirectories and files.