# Why i have got this kind of warning while using lib2xml parsing technique?

Tags: iphone, parsing, warnings, libxml2

i am getting this warning while using lib2xml in my code.

> warning: Unable to read symbols for
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1
>   (8C148a)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib
>   (file not found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this is related to the lib2xml library? Here is a [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406152/ios-4-2-1-missing-file).